# Disk writes suddenly very slow. SMART tests all report normal

Tags: hard-drive, io

I noticed that my Ubuntu workstation has become extremely slow when writing to disk. I have two hard drives, one NVME and the other SSD (both set up with ZFS). They should be able to sustain multi-GB/s write speeds; however, benchmarking them shows that they are simply not performing as intended. Running `fio --name=random-write --ioengine=posixaio --rw=randwrite --bs=4k --numjobs=1 --size=4g --iodepth=1 --runtime=60 --end_fsync=1` on the NVME gives me:

```
  WRITE: bw=13.6MiB/s (14.3MB/s), 13.6MiB/s-13.6MiB/s (14.3MB/s-14.3MB/s), io=874MiB (916MB), run=64254-64254msec
```

Running the same command on the SSD gives me:

```
  WRITE: bw=45.8MiB/s (48.0MB/s), 45.8MiB/s-45.8MiB/s (48.0MB/s-48.0MB/s), io=2753MiB (2886MB), run=60078-60078msec
```

Running the same command on a share mounted from my NAS (on a 1GB ethernet connection) gives me:

```
  WRITE: bw=100MiB/s (105MB/s), 100MiB/s-100MiB/s (105MB/s-105MB/s), io=4096MiB (4295MB), run=40818-40818msec
```

Yikes! This is pretty bad. How can I identify the problem and repair the issue? I doubt it's a problem specific to the hard drive because I'm seeing this issue on both hard drives.

Comment: Well, the SSD is 3x as fast as the hdd.  If the hdd uses Shingled Magnetic Recording (SMR), that speed is normal (might have to dig a bit, vendor may not be forthcoming on SMR).  Search this site for "slow copy"  48MB/s is right in the ballpark for copies which fill up the system buffers.

Comment: It's not a SMR or CMR HDD. It's a NVMe SSD (Adata SX8200). It's getting only 14.3 MB/s compared to my SATA SSD which is getting 48.0 MB/s.